# Where is the NullProcessing property for dimensions in OLAP cubes?

Tags: ssas, olap

I have an OLAP multidimensional cube and I changed the UnknownMember property to None for some of my dimensions where I'm confident the fact tables will always have a value for it since I have an unknown key built into the dimension table. When I went to process it threw this error for each dimension:

DimensionAttribute [Center].[Center Key]: The 'KeyColumns' #0 has NullProcessing set to 'UnknownMember', but the dimension doesn't have UnknownMember set to 'Visible' or 'Hidden'.

I can't find this NullProcessing property anywhere, hoping someone can point me in the right direction as how to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it nested under the KeyColumns property of the dimension attribute. So I went to the dimension, clicked on Center Key (under either the Dimension Structure or Attribute Relationships tab) and then expanded KeyColumns, expanded again, and found NullProcessing. I changed it from UnknownMember to Error since I'm okay with it erroring if it doesn't find one.